# Show DIV when Countdown finish

Tags: countdown, vimeo, countdowntimer

The script below shows text "EXPIRED" once the countdown has finished (you can change the time to test it) my questions is..

How to show DIV instead of text "EXPIRED" Basically I want to embed a video from VIMEO:

Emeded code for video from VIMEO.

**I thought maybe I could use "Show DIV when countdown is completed" ?**

I have a feeling that I have to make some small change to this part of the code?
**document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";**

```
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/631000875?h=612f03d2b3&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Innovate Healthcare Event"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 20, 2021 01:30:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**I hope this will help you.**

```js
// If the count down is over then run this function
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'block'; 
},3000); // 3 seconds
```

```html
<h2>Wait 3 seconds to see the div with the Iframe</h2>
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/253989945?h=c6db007fe5" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed! I manage to fix it, here's the solution..**

Countdown from your specific date to display DIV (you can put anything inside of this div)

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 22, 2021 02:22:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  '<div><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/631000875?h=612f03d2b3&amp;badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="Innovate Healthcare Event"></iframe></div>'
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```